# White hard residue on hen beak

Tags: health, chickens

3 of my BlackRock have some white hardish substance on their beak. It also seems that they might have lost a bit of weight and some weird and lay eggs with some strange marks on them. I have tried deworming them, giving them chicken spice, and always putting apple cider vinegar in their water but the illness still persists and I cannot identify what it is. They are still laying eggs although they have now stopped as they are moulting.

Can anyone recognize those symptoms and help identify the illness and how to treat it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have no experience with chicken. But beaks and eggshells have in common, that they need minerals like calcium, I assume. I do not know what is chicken spice, so maybe you tried to treaten it already.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Spices are vitamins and minerals supplements. I think the flick is suffering from roup but not entirely sure. I also thought it might a side effect of vent gleet. As the flock is mounting, I have switched their feed and will also tried corn.